# Good tool for automatic setup and deployment of Django projects

Tags: django, deployment, installation, fabric, puppet

## 2021 update

Today I'm using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) for this and other devops tasks. Along the way I've experimented with Chef, Puppet, Saltstack and Docker images, but I've found that for me,  as a solo developer working in smaller projects, a lightweight tool like Ansible is a great fit.

## Original question (from 2011)

I'm starting out as an independent web developer and I recently scared away a client by giving a quote for a rather simple
site that was quite a bit higher than they expected. It was basically
brochureware that they could have done themselves in a hosted solution
like Wordpress.com or Google sites. Except for **one** critical feature, that
made me think that Django would be a nice fit, and that some proper web
development could be motivated.

When looking at the tasks I've listed in my rough estimate it's pretty
obvious to me that most of the hours in there are stuff that is not
specific to this clients website. This got me thinking that I should
have a script to automate the process of setting up and deploying new
Django projects.

A couple of things would still have to be done manually like:

- Set up a new VPS (or in most cases just go with virtualhosts on an existing VPS).
- Edit DNS settings to point clientsdomain.com and test.clientsdomain.com
  to the new VPS.
- Set up SSH-keys
- Edit a config file.

The script would then do stuff like:

- Install some required packages on the new VPS
- Install default a iptables firewall on the new VPS
- Add nginx/apache config for clientsdomain.com and test.clientsdomain.com
- Set up new up databases for production and test on the VPS and for development on my local machine.
- Create a new Django project and put it on Bitbucket.
- Set up  settings.py and local_settings.py for production, test and development
- Set up offsite backuproutines for production database and uploaded files directory.
- Enable some default apps: flatpages, admin
- Add some boilerplate templates, a couple of boilerplate flatpages and a navbar.
- Add the 960.gs CSS-framework
- Add jQuery
- Set up djapian or Haystack (including cron job for automatic updating) for search.
- Set up a new Google analytics profile.
- Include possibility to replicate databases between production, test and development
- Set up Pingdom monitoring

I've used [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) and [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) for somewhat similar (but less ambitious)  stuff  in the past and I'm thinking that Fabric  might be a pretty good fit for this task as well, but I'd still like your input. Are there other tools I should look into? I've heard good
things about [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) but just looking at  their site (it contains the word Enterprise ) gives me the feeling that it might be overkill for a one man operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We currently do it with fabric+buildout. Others say Chef or Puppet is better suited (and it probably is, if you want to do server level stuff, not only app-level).

Also for Django there's a few dedicated hosters which take a lot of load off you, I especially like http://ep.io which we use to power our fully automated deployements for the demos of the [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/en/tour-demo/demo/), so maybe you should look into those hosting providers too rather than limiting yourself to VPSs which are more overhead for you.

Comment: Ok, I guess it might be worth to look into Puppet or Chef then.

Comment: I kind of like the flexibility and low risk of lock in that the  VPS-route provides.  I'd rather not build my deployment infrastructure around any **one** hosting provider.  I tried Webfaction though and it was pretty smooth, except for the high latency between their servers (in Texas) and my users (in Sweden).

Comment: @olvvio, completely understand that, but I just found it to be very nice to know that I don't have to worry about my servers and someone who knows what they're doing are handling that. Gives me a lot more time to think about my app rather than my servers.

Answer (score 8):

Puppet may seem daunting and overkill for small projects since it's so often used for huge deployments, but I use it to manage just one machine in [standalone mode](http://www.puppetlabs.com/blog/deploying-puppet-in-client-server-standalone-and-massively-scaled-environments) without a client server setup so that I don't have to deal with SSL certs and multiple machines, which keeps things a lot simpler, but still gives me the benefit that I can do really fast disaster recovery or move my hosting without a lot of effort.  There's some [great reasons](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/introduction.html#features-of-the-system) (idempotency, cross platform support, full lifecycle management, abstraction, concise DSLs) for using modern configuration management systems over systems that are essentially scripts that do ssh in a loop or relying on platforms that lock you in.

Check out [learning puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/) for a quick ramp up including examples and a VM playground.  You can get really useful things done with simple Puppet scripts (manifests) that run standalone, and then start learning all the advanced features once you need them.

Another nice thing is that a lot of Puppet manifests and modules have already been written by others, and they're shared on the [Puppet Forge](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/) and by many other [advanced Puppet users](http://example42.com/).

Comment: Love puppet, but as far as I can tell, Puppet Forge *only* offers modules, not manifests, which is unfortunate.

Comment: manifests are mostly going to just require the right modules with a little config passed in, and will often be specific to your setup, whereas modules are meant to be reused and not specific to your setup.  The module's README should have details how to use it from your manifest.  You're more likely to find example manifests in gists (https://gist.github.com/rcrowley/701221), but like any bit of code you find in a gist, if you can put is somewhere reusable (like a module) and call it there you'll be better off in the long run for maintainability.

Answer (score 4):

I've been considering a lot of this recently as someone in a similar position.

A lot of what you have mentioned can be helped along by setting up some good skeleton code that can be pulled from git for every new project.

Have a look at this for a good starting point for a generic django project skeleton code

http://blog.zacharyvoase.com/2010/02/03/django-project-conventions/

I put together something similar that allows me to get up and running quickly, but also to separate the server stuff from the project stuff. This is very important as it allows you to  version control every project without including system/server files. [It's here](http://hg.creativecollective.ie/skeleton/overview) (still very much in progress). This takes care of folder layout, extra css, boilerplate html stuff, grid/960 stuff, jquery, development vs production settings, database settings (mostely), default installed apps etc. Here is [the layout explained](http://hg.creativecollective.ie/skeleton/changeset/6dd556848d03#chg-README.txt)

Using [Virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), [Virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) & [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) allows you to set up standalone, encapsulated python enviroments which are great for running multiple projects on one VPS. Pip allows you to install packages to a particular virualenv and also to output all your packages to a textfile that can be imported later on. This makes redeploying code from development to production very quick. It also allows you to write a generic Requirements file in your skeleton code that automatically installs all your normal django apps i.e. django-tagging etc.

In terms of databases, I've stopped trying to have development databases and production databases on different machines, it's too hard to import/export fixtures. Now I just have separate production & dev databases on the VPS and connect remotely (over ssh) to the dev one when developing. You can easily copy one to another which is nice also.

When everything is ready then, you can deploy from development to production using fabric (i'm yet to get stuck into this so I'm not sure of its ease of use)

I'd be very interested to hear other peoples thoughts about this as I was about to post something simliar!

Comment: You've got the virtualenv files mixed in with the project instead of in ~/.virtualenvs. What's the rationale for that?

Comment: Not sure I understand? The project_root is what contains theapp (and what is submitted under a VCS). Everything in the root of the project deals with virtualenv etc., but that isn't submitted for VC.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Silk Deployment, which is based on Fabric and is used to deploy Django (or any WSGI) + Nginx + Gunicorn:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/silk-deployment/